# Is this a bug in GFortran 10?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I may have found a bug in GFortran 10.

This is a minimal example:

```
program main

  complex(8) :: x(4)

  x = 1.d0

  call print_first_element( x(4:1:-1)*x(1:4) )

  contains

  subroutine print_first_element (array)

    complex(8), intent(in) :: array(:)

    print*, array(1)

  end

end
```

Compiled with `gfortran -O3 main.f90` and executed it gives

```
(0.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
```

while I would expect the result

```
(1.0000000000000000,0.0000000000000000)
```

Strangely, it works as expected with any of the following:

1. Changing optimization flag from `-O3` to
   any of `-O2`, `-O1`, or `-O0`.
2. Using `real(8)` or `integer` instead of `complex(8)`.
3. Initializing as `complex(8) :: x(4) = [1.d0,1.d0,1.d0,1.d0]`.

Operating system and GCC version:

1. Fedora 32.
2. The output of `gfortran --version` is
   `GNU Fortran (GCC) 10.0.1 20200328`.

Do you agree it is a bug?

Comment: With "10.0.1 20200418" I see what you expect.

Comment: I get the expected output with gfortran 6.5.0, 7.5.0, 8.3.1, 9.2.1, and 10.0.0 (20200111).  If it is a bug, it is relatively new in the code base.  Perhaps, you should engage the gfortran developers as most, if not all, gfortran developers rarely read stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks to me: Seen the version in the comment from francescalus and the version specified in the question the problem seems to be solved in the mean time, but it wouldn't hurt to test it against the most recent snapshot of gfortran.

Comment: I confirm that also on GNU Fortran (GCC) 10.2.1 20200723 I get the expected result. Then, it was a bug of that version.